# Create Table and record error (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this. I got an error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE zdjecia ( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id_kategorii in' at line 8

Anyone know the reason?

```
CREATE TABLE kategorie (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nazwa VARCHAR (20) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE zdjecia (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_kategorii int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    FOREIGN KEY (id_kategorii)
    REFERENCES kategorie(id)
)

CREATE TABLE uzytkownicy (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    login VARCHAR (128) not null,
    haslo VARCHAR (128) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO 'user' ('id', 'login', 'haslo') VALUES (1, 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');
```

Comment: Each instruction must be terminated with `;` so for example `CREATE TABLE kategorie ( ... ) ;`

Comment: you have missed a , after PRIMARY KEY (id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `,` after `PRIMARY KEY (id)`

```
CREATE TABLE zdjecia (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_kategorii int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)，
    FOREIGN KEY (id_kategorii)
    REFERENCES kategorie(id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works ! but can u help me with 1 more error at

INSERT INTO 'user' ('id', 'login', 'haslo') VALUES ('1', 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'); 

#Mysql error 1064

#EDIT
INSERT INTO `galeria`.`uzytkownicy` (`id`, `login`, `haslo`) VALUES ('1', 'login', 'password');

Comment: I think you need this : INSERT INTO uzytkownicy(id, login, haslo) VALUES (1, 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');